# Incrementing a string field count in Kibana

Tags: math, kibana, amazon-opensearch

In the below query `likeCount` is a string field, but I need to do a increment operation on it, with the below query, it is doing a concatenation operation instead of increment.

```
POST /posts/_update/<id>
{
  "script" : {
    "source": "ctx._source.likeCount++"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working with below  code `Integer.toString` worked.

```
POST /posts/_update/<id>
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.likeCount = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(ctx._source.likeCount)+1);",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Making it dynamic

```
POST /posts/_update/<id>
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.likeCount = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(ctx._source.likeCount)+params.newValue);",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params" : {
      "newValue" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the number via `integer.ParseInt`:

```
POST /posts/_update/<id>
{
  "script" : {
    "source": "ctx._source.likeCount = (Integer.parseInt(ctx._source.likeCount) + 1).toString()"
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives error Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String I have already tried.